# Using AWK to print a column after calculations sent to a C file

Tags: c, bash, shell, awk, sh

My text file:

```
0000000022:tom:987:1,2:3,4
0000000223:jody:65:5,6:7,8
0000002224:ellie:43:9,8:7,6
0000022225:paul:21:5,4:3,2
0000222226:greg:0:1,2:3,4
```

My terminal command:

```
$ ./script myFile.txt 2 3 4 5
```

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file="$1"

balance=$( awk -F'[:,]' '{ print $(NF-4) }' "$file" )

fee=$( awk -F'[:,]' '{ print $(NF-3), $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $(NF) }' "$file" | ./myProgram $2 $3 $4 $5 )
```

How can I detract the fee from the balance e.g. `balanceAfter=$( balance - fee)`

I am using `awk` to go through my file and I am then sending the fields from the file and the positional parameters to myProgram.c to calculate the fee. I then want to print the name of the people in the file who don't have enough money to pay the fee. The third column is their balance. Please comment for me to clarify this if it's unclear.

The fee will end up being 28 for this case but will change depending on the different arguments and fields however in this case it would be 28 and as such should result in Paul and Greg's names being pushed to output because of their insufficient funds

My desired output after terminal command:

```
$ ./script myFile 2 3 4 5
paul
greg
```

My .c program that the fee is calculated in which is called like this:

```
$ echo 1 2 3 4 | ./myProgram 1 2 3 4
```

.c program

```
// fee calculator
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // verify parameters just in case
    if (argc != 5) {
        return 0;
    }
    char *aStr = argv[1];
    char *bStr = argv[2];
    char *cStr = argv[3];
    char *dStr = argv[4];
    // Converts parameters to integers to use in calculations
    int a = atoi(aStr);
    int b = atoi(bStr);
    int c = atoi(cStr);
    int d = atoi(dStr);
    int u1TapOn, v1TapOn, u2TapOff, v2TapOff;
    int x1, y1, x2, y2;
    int fare;
    char strCoordinates[101];
    char *ptr;
    int coordinates[4];
    while(fgets(strCoordinates, sizeof(strCoordinates), stdin) != NULL) {
        char *s = strCoordinates;
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
            coordinates[x] = strtol(s, &ptr, 10);
            s = ptr;
        }
        u1TapOn = coordinates[0];
        v1TapOn = coordinates[1];
        u2TapOff = coordinates[2];
        v2TapOff = coordinates[3];
        //Calculates (x,y) for (u1, v1) Tap On Coordinates
        x1 = (a * u1TapOn) + (b * v1TapOn);
        y1 = (c * u1TapOn) + (d * v1TapOn);
        //Calculates (x,y) for (u2, v2) Tap Off Coordinates
        x2 = (a * u2TapOff) + (b * v2TapOff);
        y2 = (c * u2TapOff) + (d * v2TapOff);
        //Calculates the fare for each line of the input
        fare = abs(x1 - x2) + abs(y1 - y2);
        printf("%d\n", fare);   
    }       
    return 0;
}
```

The logic for the calculations is that the file represents a group of people with cards with money on them. They have a valid card number, name, balance, coordinates to calculate distance travelled to figure out the fee.

The script should see who doesn't have enough money in their balance to pay the fee and then print their names. The script should take parameters to adjust the fee value

Comment: This seems like a very convoluted way to do this. Also both fee and balance will contain all the lines in them so will not work if you try to subtract them, and neither will toms answer below for the same reason. It would be better to do all of this in awk.

Comment: Is this a typo `2 3 45`?

Comment: I really have the feeling your under using awk and that you should be less specific on your questions to get a better way to do it. I think you have some requirements to extract people from the colon separated file on different uses cases. A question could be 'starting from this file, I have to [..list of things to do ...], Some parameters are given by an external progam which takes this and this as parameters, I've tried this with awk [...exemple..] but didn't get expected output or it's really slow (too much calls), how could this be improved.' (This is just my opinion of course)

Comment: @Tensibai Completely agree that the expected end result would be far more useful.

Comment: @JID I think you're right. It was a typo, I fixed that up. Do you know a good place for me to look to see how to do this with a better awk command. This is my first shell script. The same people are answering. Thank you so much for you're help.

Comment: @Tensibai Also thank you and do you know how I could better use AWK or where to read up on AWK to better learn how to implement it for my purpose

Comment: I want to print the name column when the balance isnt negative after the fee is deducted after being calculated in the .c program

Comment: You can [start here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) and searching on SO inside the awk tag can help finding specific cases usually.

Comment: @JoshuaVernon you can look [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk).html to learn how to structure awk commands and the basic syntax. Then just use the [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/) for more specific functions and solutions. As you have made an effort though i am sure people on here would be glad to help. If you provide the logic for the calculations then i would probably be able to create a script for you and explain how it works.

Comment: @JID thank you I'll go through the two links you sent me. I posted my .c program and some more info but if it's not explained well don't worry you've already helped immensly

Comment: @Tensibai Thank you so much for you're help I'll check out that link. What did you mean by search on SO inside the awk tag? I'm also looking on the man page in terminal

Comment: I appreciate that you're trying to provide as much detail as possible but there are still some things that are unclear. Are you trying to call your program once, using the first line of your file? That's what it looks like at the moment. Your question is becoming too broad as you add more of the "story". You should instead focus on a specific requirement, ideally **one thing** that you're having trouble with. Please edit your question and attempt to simplify it as much as possible, so we can help you more easily.

Comment: @TomFenech I disagree, whilst adding more information has made it more complex, it hasn't become any more broad, if anything the specification has become narrower as we can now see the logic behind the expected output.

Comment: @JoshuaVernon Does abs make the number positive, i haven't used it before ?

Comment: @JID yes its the absolute value as part of the math.h header file. I believe you can also use fabs() for floating point numbers

Comment: @JID perhaps it was not the best choice of word. I meant that the solution is likely to become longer and address more separate issues. By the way, yes, `abs` returns the absolute (positive) value. Although if you're planning on rewriting a solution involving a shell script, several awk one-liners and a C program into an awk script, I would definitely say that's heading towards answering a question that's too broad!

Comment: @TomFenech I think it's not that complex at end, I hope I got the correct idea in my answer. (need to get away from keyboard for a while)

Comment: It should just be one shell script that calls my c program. The c program is finished, I posted it because I thought it might make more sense seeing where the arguments are going. If it confuses the issue I apologise. The issue I need help with is how to write my shell script so it prints only the names if the balance less than the fee. The fee is gotten by calling my c program. But the end result should just be the printed names

Comment: @JoshuaVernon Using your logic i get 20(not 28) as the fare for all of them passing in `1 2 3 4`.Nvm get 28 when passing `2 3 4 5`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All in awk

```
awk -F[,:] -vx="2,3,4,5" '
{
        split(x,a)
        x1=(a[1]*$4)+(a[2]*$5)
        y1=(a[3]*$4)+(a[4]*$5)
        x2=(a[1]*$6)+(a[2]*$7)
        y2=(a[3]*$6)+(a[4]*$7)
        fare=(x1-x2)+(y1-y2)
        fare<0&&fare*=-1}
fare>$3{print $2}
' test
```

If you want to use your c program it would probably be better to use a while loop

```
while read line;do
        fare=$(awk -F[:,] '{$1=$2=$3=""}1' <<< "$line" | tester.c 2 3 4 5)
        name=$(awk -F[:,] '{print $2}' <<< "$line" )
        balance=$( awk -F[:,] '{ print $3 }' <<< "$line")
        ((fare > balance)) && echo $name
done < test
```

---

#### Output

```
paul
greg
```

---

#### Explanation

> Awk

```
-F[,:] -vx="2,3,4,5"
```

Sets field sep to `,` or `;`.
Sets variable x to the value you want to use in the calculation. Can also pass them as them as args if in another script like `-vx="$2,$3,$4,$5"`

```
split(x,a)
```

This splits the args passed in x into separate array variables in array `a`. It creates these by splitting x based on the field separator we made earlier.

```
x1=(a[1]*$4)+(a[2]*$5)
...
fare=(x1-x2)+(y1-y2)
```

Calculations based on logic from c program.

```
fare<0&&fare*=-1}
```

Converts to positive number if negative.

```
fare>$3{print $2}
```

Prints the name in `field 2` if `field 3` is less than the fare.

> Loop

```
while read line;do
...
done < test
```

For each line in the file test

```
fare=$(awk -F[:,] '{$1=$2=$3=""}1' <<< "$line" | tester.c 2 3 4 5)
```

Remove the first 3 fields, the line is recompiled automatically by (g)awk when a field is changed. The default Output field separator is space, the last 4 fields are piped to tester.c in the correct format.

`<<<` is a here string that passes the string to awk as though it were a file/stdin. This way we can pass each line to awk separately.

```
name=$(awk -F[:,] '{print $2}' <<< "$line" )
balance=$( awk -F[:,] '{ print $3 }' <<< "$line")
```

Same concept to set the other variables.

```
((fare > balance)) && echo $name
```

`((...))` is the `let` command which allows mathematic equations and comparisons to be executed.

`&&` used like this means don't execute the next command unless the first returns true

`echo $name` Pretty self explanatory.

Any more information needed let me know :)

---

Resources

http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/let  (let `((...))`)
https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/  (awk stuff)
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html (Here string `<<<`)

Comment: What is the `<<< $line` doing? Is it making it just read a line at a time for the while loop?

Comment: @JoshuaVernon added explanations

Comment: Thank you I'll go through all of these!!! The here string is awesome, thats what I was looking for it seems. Only thing I guess is wha is the `< text` after done doing?

Comment: @JoshuaVernon http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/redircb.html#REDIRREF. It is pretty much just the same as piping cat file into the loop but allows more flexibility and doesn't need to run another process for cat.

Comment: I'm using the second option the loop. I am however getting only paul as output. Any reason it would be stopping at the first instance of a balance lower than the fee. I posted my script as an answer of which I can delete after I just wanted it to be easy to read.

Comment: @JoshuaVernon no idea, Just ran your script you posted and get both. I ran `./Script file 2 3 4 5`. Are you sure there isn't something different to what you have posted here. e.g input file is slightly different or whatever.

Comment: Yep my txt file didn't have a new line character for the last line as I had typed it into the txt file using text edit. I recreated it using unix touch and cat commands. Worked perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to give you a commented exemple with awk on this specific case: (warning untested code)

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f    
BEGIN { FS =[:,] } # Set the Field Separator

{  #Do this for each line (no selector before the block)
  "./myprogram" $4 $5 $6 $7 | getline fee[$2] # Get the fee value by calling the program with the 4 last fields from line and startan array of fee with username as key for later use
  close("./myprogram") # To empty the buffer and avoid errors after
  resultingbalance[$2]= $3 - fee[$2] # some math to get the resulting balance for user, same into an array with user as key
} 

END { # Important keyword, this code will run after the end of file has been reached
  for (i in resultingbalance) { # loop over the array
    if ((resultingbalance[i]) < 0) { # is the relusting balance negative ?
      print i," can't pay its travel. Fee:",fee[i]," Balance at  end:",resultingbalance[i] # if yes, print the key (username), the fee and the balance at end accessign the arrays
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this will help

Comment: I would recommend using an awk script rather than a "one-liner" in order to improve clarity. You also need to do something about the apostrophe in "can't" within your code (not using a one-liner would help here).